# Non-frequentist Consistency of Bayesian Estimates

Tags: bayesian, frequentist, consistency

this question seems weird. But I am just wondering if there exists any sorts of theories about 'non-frequentist consistency' of Bayesian methods? So far all the results I found are about the consistency result in a frequentist point of view.

Comment: What exactly do you have in mind? What kind of consistency?

Comment: In the frequentist point of view, the data is generate from a fixed but unknown parameter. So the frequentist consistency of Bayes estimator means the posterior density converges to a point mass of the 'true' parameter. But I am wondering if there is some theorem assuming the 'true parameter' follows a distribution instead of a point mass, and some theorem stating that when sample size are large enough, the posterior density converges to the true distribution, instead of a point mass.

Comment: Note that by Bernstein-von Mises (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%E2%80%93von_Mises_theorem) the MAP Bayesian estimator converges to the MLE, so, if the MLE is consistent, so will the MAP be.